# How to compress log files with NLog

Tags: compression, nlog

I am using NLog in one of my projects and I am trying to have the output of the files to be compressed.
I tried to use the compress file attribute, but when I look at the files, they are not compressed.

Could you please tell me what I might be doing wrong?

This is my config:

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <targets>  
        <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\Workspaces\log.xml"
                layout="${message}" keepFileOpen="true"
                archiveFileName = "C:\Workspaces\archived\log.{#####}.xml"
                archiveAboveSize = "1048576" archiveNumbering = "Sequence"
                fileAttributes="Compressed" concurrentWrites =  "true"/>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name ="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Is file compression enabled on the drive? Create a normal file with some content, make a copy and then mark this copy as compressed - compare the file size of the two.

Comment: That seems like a solution through the OS, but not the solution I am looking for. Example given: What if I want to move that file to another system, will it still be compressed?

Comment: it seems to be a reported bug, [you could comment in git-hub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/244) so they can give this issue more priority

Answer (score 10):

With NLog 4, you can compress to `zip` files (.NET 4.5+). See [the NLog 4.0 release post](http://nlog-project.org/2015/06/09/nlog-4-has-been-released.html)

Use `enableArchiveFileCompression` as follows:

```xml
<target name="file" xsi:type="File"
      layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}" 
      fileName="${basedir}/logs/logfile.txt" 
      archiveFileName="${basedir}/archives/log.{#}.zip"
      archiveEvery="Day"
      archiveNumbering="Rolling"
      maxArchiveFiles="7"
    enableArchiveFileCompression="true" />
```

Comment: In this way you are creating zip files but with .txt extension right? Mine was unreadable to me, after I rename it with the .zip extension I was able to read the log file in it.

Comment: Thx,  fixed the copy paste bug :)